# In MySQL, how can I find the sum of the N largest values grouped on a particular column?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

I have the following data.

```
id      val
smith   20
smith   10
smith    8
smith   30
jones   40
jones   10
jones   30
jones   30
```

What I want then is to group by id and sum the two largest values for each id.

```
smith   50  from 30+20
jones   70  from 40+30
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you weren't worried about getting the sum of only the top two values for each ID, you would want this:

```
SELECT SUM(val) FROM table_name GROUP BY id ORDER BY id ASC
```

However, the "How do I get the top N values within a group" question is a duplicate, answered here: [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)